# Google Drive SDK Update sharing permissions

Tags: google-drive-api

Is there an option to change the sharing settings trough drive SDK?

If I add permissions at user level with a email Id. I can see the visibility perms of doc as *Private*.
If I set permission to { 'value': None, 'type': "anyone", 'role': "writer"}. I can see the visibility perms of doc as "*Public on the web*".

[image]

Can any help, what settings can set sharing settings to *Anyone with link*.

The issue with public on web is we could see anonymous users are able to find the doc and we could see unknown presence on the doc..

Comment: Did you try by adding withLink:true? According to the API (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions) concerning permissions, you can add more variables to define them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
'value' => 'me', 'type' => 'anyone', 'role' => 'reader', 'withLink' => true
```

This will change sharing settings to Anyone with link.

Comment: Thanks, got it resolved.
this permission set solved the issues: { 'value': None , 'type': "anyone", 'role': "writer" }

Answer (score 2):

Try [this link](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert) with the following values

> 'value' = 'me',  'type' = 'anyone',  'role' = 'reader'