# Google Drive SDK - change item sharing permissions

Tags: google-drive-api

according to the [Google Drive SDK Update sharing permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386416/google-drive-sdk-update-sharing-permissions) and https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions I want to change the whole folder content to be available for viewing (the folder contains only images and I show them on my page with `<img alt='' src='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id="fileID"'/>`)

so, I'm trying to use that code

```
PermissionList permissions = Google_DriveService.Permissions.List(fileId).Fetch();
var filePermissions =  permissions.Items;


Permission permission = Google_DriveService.Permissions.Get(fileId, filePermissions[0].Id).Fetch();
permission.Role = "reader";
permission.Value = "me";
permission.Type =  "anyone";
permission.WithLink = true;

var updated = Google_DriveService.Permissions.Update(permission, fileId, filePermissions[0].Id).Fetch();
```

but I get the error message

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError Invalid permission type specified [400] Errors [ Message[Invalid permission type specified] Location[ - ] Reason[invalid] Domain[global] ]
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change permission types with update requests, insert a new permission and delete the existing. You should also not use `me` as a principal related to an anyone permission. Anyone permissions dont expect value attributes to be set.

Comment: I've added a new permission with that values and it worked. I didn't delete the primary permission

Answer (score 3):

Tony's answer is correct and here is an addon to his instruction if anyone else is looking to test this. Note that I did not write up the code for this due to time constraints but I tested it using the Google API supplied on the Google Drive web api page. I tested this by doing the following:

1. Go to the following link and list all the files in your drive. https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list
2. Select one file that you want to share for read only access and copy out the "id" as per the screenshot below:

[image: drive id]

Go to the insert permission page here - Tony was correct, you do not delete the existing permission but instead, you add onto that permission: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert

3. In the API explorer, type in "role" as "reader" and "type" as "anyone".
4. Go to your Drive: https://drive.google.com/drive/#my-drive and you will see that the file is now shared - if you hover over the green link icon in the screenshot below, it will tell you that it is now shared.

[image: Drive shared]

You can also copy the link for the doc and paste it into Incognito mode in Chrome to test whether you can access the read-only version of the doc in Incognito mode and it should work.

**Additional:**

The code should not be too hard, here it is:

```
 Permission newPermission = new Permission();

    newPermission.setType("anyone");
    newPermission.setRole("reader");
    try {
      return service.permissions().insert(fileId, newPermission).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
    }
```

Comment: where should i call this POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/fileId/permissions

and what is the use of the scope

Answer (score 0):

This is the new reference of the API: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions/create